# Modeling "specific products" database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, rdbms

I am new to Hibernate and ORM in general.

I've got a *Product* entity which holds properties such as *description, price, barcode* and other product generics.

Now I want to manage other product specific data, e.g. I can imagine a *Sunglasses* entity with information about lenses, size .... and a *Watch* entity with other details related to shape, battery duration and so on.

Which is the better strategy? In a "non-ORM" world I would have had:

- two tables: watches and sunglasses, with duplicated fields
- one table: "products" with ALL properties from watches and glasses and a field "kindOfProduct"

How can I model that on Hibernate/JPA?

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL, check out the hstore module. It allows you to effeciently assign dynamic attributes for a single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mainly have three inheritance strategies to choose from. The two you mentioned in the question, plus a mixed one, which stores the common attributes into a base table, and the specific properties into specialized tables.

But with only this information, it's a bit hard to give an advice, as there are rules and constraints on what you can accomplish with each of the strategies. I'd suggest to start by reading the Hibernate documentation on this topic and experimenting by yourself:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/manual/en-US/html_single/#d0e7071

Answer (score 1):

How about making it more generic and having one product class and each product can have a list of "product features".

This could be mapped via a many to many relationship and will allow you to add as many different types of products and features as you need.

Each product could still have the product type field so you know what type of product you are dealing with.